# Blazor (Server) not updating image using StateHasChanged();

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm creating a blazor server App that should read the Webcam and show the Image, and while the Image generates fine (the base64 is completely valid) it's not updating the image on the Website even when using InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

Index.razor:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>


<div style="width: 100%; height: 500px;border: solid green 1px">
    <img src="@ImageSource" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: auto; border: solid red 1px;" 
         />
</div>


@code
{

    public string? ImageSource { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("init");

        Webcam.Instance?.Init(async bufferScope =>
        {
            byte[] image = bufferScope.Buffer.ExtractImage();
            var ms = new MemoryStream(image);
            ImageSource = ToBase64Image(Bitmap.FromStream(ms));
            _forceRerender = true;
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            Console.WriteLine("running again");
        }, true);
    }

    public static string ToBase64Image(Image bmp)
    {
        var data = GetPng(bmp);

        return "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(data.ToArray());
    }

    public static byte[] GetPng(Image bitmap)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    bool _forceRerender = false;

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        if (_forceRerender)
        {
            _forceRerender = false;
            return true;
        }
        return base.ShouldRender();
    }

}
```

If that helps here is my (rudimentary) webcam class (yes i know the way i have it isn't best practise but i wan't it to at least run):

```
using FlashCap;

namespace CameraServer.Data
{
    public class Webcam
    {
        public static Webcam? Instance { get; private set; }

        private CaptureDeviceDescriptor DeviceDescriptor { get; set; }

        public CaptureDevice Device { get; private set; }

        public Webcam(CaptureDeviceDescriptor deviceDescriptor)
        {
            DeviceDescriptor = deviceDescriptor;

            Instance = this;
        }

        public async Task<Webcam?> Init(PixelBufferArrivedDelegate func, bool start = false)
        {
            Device = await DeviceDescriptor.OpenAsync(DeviceDescriptor.Characteristics[0], func);

            if (start)
                await Device.StartAsync();

            return Instance;
        }

        //signal webcam to start
        public void Start() => Device?.StartAsync();


        //stop webcam (videoSource.WaitForStop(); to check)
        public void Stop() => Device?.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your anonymous method attached to `Webcam.Instance?.Init` into a named method and using breakpoints make sure it's getting called when the webcam updates and what image you are getting.

Comment: I see no evidence that the Webcam constructor is ever called.

Comment: The Constructor is called at startup in the Program.cs, the Image also generates completely fine. I used the debugger to check the Value in ImageSource, it's a fully working image that when transplanted works as expected. I'll try using a named method

Comment: Now it's cleaner but didn't help :(

Comment: Any idea how often that PixelBufferArrivedDelegate  delegate is called? Is your App still responsive?

Comment: The App is completely responsive. The Delegate is called at the Webcam Framerate so up to 60 times a second. But in this case it's more likely to be <=30 times

Comment: So is the callback function getting constantly called?  Add a global string variable, populate it with `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()` every time the callback is called, and display the variable on the page.  Does it update?.

Comment: If the callback is being called, and `ImageSource` is changing then `<img ....` should be being refreshed.  Does the Url change, is there cacheing involved?

Comment: The Variable isn't updating too, neither is the URL changing, i don't know if caching is involved. The Variable is changing like ImageSource does. But the Page isn't showing it

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a similar problem: The Issue was solved by changing the render-mode in _Host.cshtml from "ServerPrerendered" to "Server".

Thanks everyone who tried to help!

Comment: That alone cannot explain the error. The main difference is that with ServerPrerendered Index.OnInitializedAsync() is called twice. You will now probably see the same issue when you change pages.

Comment: Yes that's the case, but i already expected that. This can (and has been) fixed by moving the methods that generate the Image to the Webcam class and Getting the source from there. However without changing the rendering this wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).